# MySQL many to many relation table

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, eclipselink, mariadb

I have two tables which are connected but but the relation is ManyToOne but i want to change it to ManyToMany because it's suits it better but when creating new ManyToMany table.

Tables

```
CostCenter
IdCostCenter CostCenterNumber CostCenterName
1            1                Name 1 
2            2                Name 2


TravelCostCenterLine
IdCostCenterLine IdTravelComponent  SplitLine Percentage IdCostCenter
1                      1                0        25           1
2                      1                0        25           2
3                      1                1        30           1
4                      1                1        20           2
5                      2                0        100          1
```

So I want to change it to many to many that one TravelCostCenterLine has multiple CostCenter and same CostCenter can be assigned to multiple lines

So for that i need many to many relation table to look like this but i don't know how to make an insert to fill info :

```
LineCostCenterMapping
IdLineCostCenterMapping IdCostCenter SplitLine IdTravelComponent
1                            1          0            1
1                            2          0            1
2                            1          1            1
2                            2          1            1
3                            1          0            2
```

I started writing the insertion query which would fill data for this table but i don't know how to complete it

```
INSERT INTO LineCostCenterMapping (IdCostCenter, SplitLine, IdTravelComponent)
      SELECT
        ce.IdCostCenter,
        tcl.SplitLine,
        tcl.IdTravelComponent
      FROM TravelCostCenterLine tcl
        JOIN
        CostCenter
        ce ON tcl.IdCostCenter = ce.IdCostCenter;
```

So it would look like LineCostCenterMapping example

Comment: in mapping table just store IdCostCenter and IdCostCenterLine

Comment: Yeah this is another way but then how to write the query to fill data ?

Comment: [_Mapping table advice_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 1):

there is no special syntax to fill a many-to-many table, it's the usual insert statement, however the values that you will insert in **LineCostCenterMapping** should already exists in **CostCenter** and **TravelCostCenterLine**. to ensure this constraint you can use in the GUI for example a Combobox or an autocomplete field with existing values of **CostCenter**, **TravelCostCenterLine**

could you give more information about your application : programming language , DBMS ...

Comment: I understand that it's simple insert but i'm not sure how to build it in order to get this result, It's JAVA mainly EJBs, EclipseLink JPA and MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to create a new table.
So for example table will look like:

---

```
CostCenter

IdCostCenter CostCenterNumber CostCenterName
1            1                Name 1 
2            2                Name 2

TravelCostCenterLine

IdCostCenterLine IdTravelComponent  SplitLine Percentage
1                      1                0        25          
2                      1                0        25          
3                      1                1        30          
4                      1                1        20          
5                      2                0        100
```

Then you should create new table with those two table relational ids

```
third_table

id      costCenterid               TravelCostCenterLine
1   primary_key_of_first_table     primary_key_of_second_table
```

last table will hold relations between two base table.